# Can I make an after_commit callback in an observer only fire on update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

ActiveRecord has [many callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) including an after_commit callback, which is nice, but in the case of [observers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html) there doesn't seem to be a way to have it only be in effect on update and not create, or vice-versa.

Is there a way to get this behavior? Something like...

```
def after_commit
  return unless self.was_just_updated
  # .....
end
```

Comment: Untested, but you may want to try this https://coderwall.com/p/f5-vlq

Comment: In the observer class you define e.g. `after_update`, and either not define `after_create` (or have it empty), or you mean that you don't want the observer to react at all when e.g. create?

Comment: @vise interesting, thanks. actually i realized after i typed this that i can check of `created_at == updated_at`, which will always be true on creation time and always false when updated.

Comment: @244an but those will put the actions before the transaction is closed. i need it after the transaction is closed.

Answer (score 1):

the answer...

```
def after_commit
  return if created_at == updated_at
  # .....
end
```